# react native widget library or method for creating widgets

Tags: react-native

I want to create a widget for my react native app.

I should control multiple buttons on my widget and be able to get the states of those buttons to be used on other components inside my app.

I already set my redux and want to control buttons with redux.

which react native library works best in my case?
I searched so much but didn't reach what I wanted so far.